# Given two binary lists of same length, how to find all the pair of indices corresponding to ones of alternating lists without ones in between?

Tags: python, list, function, performance, binary

Suppose you have two lists L1 and L2 of same length, each having only 0 and 1 values. How to efficiently find all the pairs of indices `[i, j]` such that:

1. `i < j`
2. `L1[i] == 1 and L2[j] == 1`
3. For any `k` such that `i < k < j` we have `L1[k] == 0 and L2[k] == 0`

Example:

```
L1 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
L2 = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
```

Expected output:

```
[[0, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
```

My following code works, but it is extremely slow for large computations. I am looking for a much faster solution.

```
import math

def getNext(ind,i):
    nextList = [idx for idx,x in enumerate(ind) if (x and idx>i)]
    if nextList:
        return min(nextList)
    else:
        return math.inf
    
def getPrevious(ind,i):
    previousList = [idx for idx,x in enumerate(ind) if (x and idx<i)]
    if previousList:
        return max(previousList)
    else:
        return -math.inf

def getIndices(list1,list2):
    indices = [[i,j] for i,x in enumerate(list1) 
                     for j,y in enumerate(list2)
                     if x and y and i<j and getNext(list1,i,'true') >= j
                        and getPrevious(list2,j,'true') <= i
              ] 
    return indices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the `i` that refers to a 1 in the first list while doing a single iteration. When you encounter a 1 in the other list that follows in the next iterations after that, you have a tuple for output. Whenever you have such a hit, forget the `i` (set it to -1 or something other invalid index or None) and continue:

```
def find_pairs(lst1, lst2):
    i = -1
    for j, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)):
        if b and i != -1: # End of a range
            yield i, j
            i = -1  # Invalidate starting index of range
        if a:  # Start a new range
            i = j
```

Example call with a less trivial input than you posted in the question:

```
lst1 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
lst2 = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]
print(list(find_pairs(lst1, lst2)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 7), (8, 10), (10, 11)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try version with generators:

```
L1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
L2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]


from itertools import count


def get_pairs(L1, L2):
    c = count(1)
    L2, L1 = zip(
        *[
            (next(c) if i == 1 else 0, next(c) if j == 1 else 0)
            for i, j in zip(L2, L1)
        ]
    )

    i1 = ((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(L1) if v != 0)
    i2 = ((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(L2) if v != 0)

    try:
        (idx1, v1), (idx2, v2) = next(i1), next(i2)
        while True:
            while v1 - v2 != -1:
                if idx1 < idx2:
                    idx1, v1 = next(i1)
                else:
                    idx2, v2 = next(i2)
            yield idx1, idx2
            idx1, v1 = next(i1)
    except StopIteration:
        pass


print(list(get_pairs(L1, L2)))
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 7), (8, 10), (10, 11)]
```